# What books explain most comprehensively the lure and reward method of dog training?

Tags: dogs, training

Having first read some reviews of several books on canine clicker training, in the hunt for works that experienced trainers would list among the "must read" books on the subject, I have now finished Karen Pryor's *Reaching the Animal Mind* and I am part-way through her earlier *Don't Shoot the Dog*. Pryor has been a leading figure in the development of the marker method as it has been used with dolphins, dogs, and other species, including humans. In my opinion in the first three-quarters or so of her first-mentioned book she gives an admirably clear and waffle-free explanation of the marker method as it is used with dogs (and a clicker) as well as with other species (such as dolphins, with whom the usual marker is a whistle).

Since she expounds a method that uses positive reinforcement only, it is no surprise that she criticises the traditional use of dominance and aversion. But she is also critical of lure and reward, a rival positive approach, which she views as likely to produce dogs who are overly passive even when the method is used together with a clicker.

I wish to form my own opinion on this other positive method that she is criticising. So my question is as follows. What books have you read that, in light of your practical experiences, you believe most comprehensively explain the lure and reward method of training dogs and the ideas that underlie it? Perhaps there are some books by some of the key figures who developed this approach? At the moment, I don't even know who those figures are. I know some of the popular writers, but not who the main shapers of the method have been. (For the clicker method there is Pryor and then the line goes back through at least three of B F Skinner's students.)

(Note: I phrased this question after reading the help file. It is intended to be "constructive subjective", "[inviting the] sharing [of] experiences over opinions" and soliciting only "opinion [that is] backed up with facts and references".)